# Why isn't the background colour for my header applying?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to apply a dark navy colour to my header but it isn't working. Would appreciate some guidance on this, thanks!

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  Dashboard: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#14172B'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

'DefaultNavigationOptions' is a configuration option for the stack. To configure separately, it must be configured as 'NavigationOptions' as in the login screen.

```js
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#14172B'
      }
```